# Set the width of an element like its height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I found some links how to set the height of an element like its width with the margin/padding trick (http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html). But I want to set the width of an element like its height.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 50px; /* changing this value ... */
  width: 300px;
}

.label {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}

.icon {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px; /* <- ... should set this value to the same size */
  background: red;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/melurilefe/edit?html,css,output

So the element has a height of 100% and when the height of its parent changes from, let's say 50px to 100px, the width of the element should mirror that size so it always stays a square.

Is that possible with just CSS? Thanks!

Comment: You can set both the height and width by using `vh` (viewport height) or `vw` (viewport width). Unfortunately that would mean you cannot scale based on the elements parents, but only the viewports size.

Comment: I guess I came up with a solution but it's to dirty so I guess I will build the component different. One could build the element with flex-direction: column and rotate it by 90deg and use the link I postet in the question. Then one has to rotate the content as well et voila ;)

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to use javaScript and run it every time you load or resize a page. That's not your question however.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know there are no dynamic solutions using just CSS .

What you can do if you want to change the values easier ( but it's not dynamic )

Use **CSS Variable** . Set a value to that variable and use it both for with and height of the two elements. When you change the value of that variable, both will width and height will change

Else, you need to use something like javascript/jQuery to have width depending on parent height

See below

```css
:root {
  --height-width: 50px;
}


.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
  height: var(--height-width); /* changing this value ... */
  width: 300px;
}

.label {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}

.icon {
  height: 100%;
  width: var(--height-width); /* <- ... should set this value to the same size */
  background: red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="label">Hey</div>
    <div class="icon">i</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as setting the `.icon{width: 50px}` and `.container{height: 50px}`. The variable technically has no use.

Comment: it has if you have many items to change . So you change only in one place. That's what variables are for. I don;t know why the op wants to have that changed . There is a possibility he wants to change to multiple elements at once. But yes, there's not much of a difference. I just offered an alternative and also i said in my answer that as far as i know there's no css only  solution for this

Comment: If you define the width and height separately you don't have to deal with browser support of variables; http://caniuse.com/css-variables/embed . This approach also wouldn't work with percentages. For those reasons I can't really recommend your approach over simply setting your variables. If those restrictions aren't an issue for the OP it's a pretty good solution.

Comment: unfortunately it has to change responsive and not just once :(

Comment: @user2170547 well if you want dynamic. Then you can't do that with only css..unfortunately. I can make you a simple solution with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to do that:
You can get the width of an element by `offsetWidth` method.

```js
let div = document.getElementById("demo");
div.style.height = div.offsetWidth + "px";
```

This code will run once on reload the page so it is not dynamic. If you want to make it dynamic you can put it on `onresize` event like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
  let div = document.getElementById("demo");
  div.style.height = div.offsetWidth + "px";
})
```

```js
let demo = document.getElementById("demo");
demo.style.height = demo.offsetWidth + "px";
```

```css
div {
  background-color:red;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"> This is a div </div>
```